# listview smoothscrolltoposition(position) always jumping to the first item

Tags: android

I am developing an application where i need to update the listview items(i.e calling setAdapter() frequently,inner data set of adapter may change, but think that it is not changing now) whenever user comes back to the application(from another app,that is, after switching to another app and coming back again). my goal is to scroll back to the position where i left the app. But whenever i am coming back, listview is jumping to the first item in the list.

my code is:

```
int last_list_pos=-1; //global variable

.
.
.
.
.

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    list.smoothScrollToPosition(last_list_pos);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    last_list_pos=list.getFirstVisiblePosition();
}
```

Comment: Can you move code from onStop to onPause and check.

Comment: The problem was solved... i did not remember about a background thread that was loading data to the adapter, it was causing the error. Anyway, thanks...